# how to convert datetime to short date?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, c#-4.0

i have a table called as X and this table has a field known as X_DateTime respectively, which has value like 2012-03-11 09:26:37.837.

i want to convert the above datetime value to this format yyyy-MM-dd (2012-03-11) and literally remove the Time (09:26:37.837)

i have used something like below code

```
DateTimeFormatInfo format = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
format.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
format.DateSeparator = "-";
DateTime date = 2012-03-11 09:26:37.837;
DateTime shortDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date , format);
```

please help me...

i am using C# as my language.

thanks,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must call `.ToString()` method with that format that you want. In your example it will be like this.

```
DateTime date=DateTime.Now;
var shortDate=date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Or if you want to keep `DateTime` type, you must call `.Date` property of `DateTime`

```
DateTime date=DateTime.Now;
var shortDate=date.Date;
```

From MSDN

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
>   set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime dateToDisplay = new DateTime(2014, 11, 03, 42, 50);
String shortDateTime = dateToDisplay.ToShortDateString();
```

Then you can convert this shortDateTime to datetime like this

```
DateTime shortDate = Convert.ToDateTime(shortDateTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

This works good as well:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.BirthDate);
item.BirthDate = date.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following :

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

I was taking DateTime from Database as string. converted it to DateTime and I cutted the time from it. Here is what I have done.

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.BirthDate);
item.BirthDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeFormatInfo format = new DateTimeFormatInfo(); 
format.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"; 
format.DateSeparator = "-"; 
DateTime date = 2012-03-11 09:26:37.837; 
DateTime shortDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date , format);
```

Answer (score 0):

easy and to the point:
new Date(Date.now()).toString() - the shorten version